# On click change p to texarea field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a paragraph and I want to change it to textarea on click. Not with some extra button but with direct click on paragraph itself and after editing with a click outside of currently textarea back to paragraph using javascript or jquery. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: `contenteditable` is the attribute you're looking for

Comment: And what you have tried so far in coding to achieve the same?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: I wasn't asking for a written code, I was asking for a suggestion (as written). The answer from Alex, which attribute to use was more then enough. Btw thanks Alex!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my input.

I have used [`contenteditable`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_contenteditable.asp) attribute to toggle the editing of the `div`.

---

```js
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
 $('.textarea').attr('contentEditable', false);
});

$('.textarea').on('click', function(e) {
 $(this).attr('contentEditable', true);
 e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
.textarea {
 border: 1px solid;
}

[contenteditable="true"] {
 border: 2px solid red;
}

span {
 background: grey;
 padding: 1.25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="textarea" contenteditable="false">
 Hello World. This is a super awesome paragraph that you can edit using <span>contenteditable</span> attribute on click.
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the below code to solve your problem:

```js
$('#myDiv').click(function(e){
    
    $('p').contents().unwrap().wrap('<textarea/>');
    e.stopPropagation()
    
});

$('#myBdy').click(function(){

 $('textarea').contents().unwrap().wrap('<p/>');
   
});
```

```css
#myDiv {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body id="myBdy">
<div id="myDiv">
<p id="myP">Hi</p>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: You probably want an on blur too for the second bit